# Fake proof for "differentiability implies continuous derivative": review

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

We known that a function may be differentiable at a point while having discontinuous derivative at such point. The following exercise proposes a fake proof for the proposition "let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be everywhere continuous and differentiable, then $f'$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$"; I am asked to find the mistake(s).

We prove that, for every $ a \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow} f'(x)=f'(a)$. Fix a point $a \in \mathbb{R}$, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x>a$, $f$ is continuous on $[a,x]$ and differentiable on $(a,x)$, hence by MVT there exists a point $\xi \in (a,x)$ such that: $$ \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = f'(\xi) $$Now, the limit of the LHS when $x \rightarrow a$ exists (and equals $f'(a)$ since $f$ is differentiable at $x=a$), so does the limit of the RHS. Finally, notice that when $x \rightarrow a$, then  $c \rightarrow a$, leading to: $$  f'(a)=\lim_{\xi \rightarrow a} f'(\xi). $$
My thought is that the trick lies in the worlds "when $x \rightarrow a$, then  $\xi \rightarrow a$": $\xi$ is in fact a function of $x$ (even if not explicitly said) $\xi=\xi(x)$, so the previous assertion somehow requires the continuity of $\xi(x)$. Is that idea correct or there is something else I couldn't see?

Comment: The sequence of points satisfying the MVT might not be a representative sequence. I.e., say the derivative was $1$ on the irrationals and $0$ on the rationals. Then if $a$ is rational, you might have that each $\xi(x,a)$ is also rational, but this doesn't tell you that the $\delta-\epsilon$ condition for continuity is satisfied for a small irrational $\xi$.

Comment: In short, just because you have a function $\xi(x)$ that tends to $a$ as $x\to a$, $\xi$ might not achieve all values near $a$. To guarantee continuity, you need to know about how $f'$ behaves at all values near $a$.

Comment: I'm not sure I got it. So the problem is not about the continuity of the "Lagrange point function", but it's about the operation of limit itself with that as a variabile? Has this something to do with accumulation points?

Comment: Continuity of $f'$ means for any sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that $x_n \to x$, then $f'(x_n) \to f'(x)$. You just showed this holds for a sequence of $\xi$'s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, when $x\to a$, indeed $\xi(x)\to a$, since $a<\xi(x)<x$. Or, in other words, $\xi(\bullet)$ is continuous at $a$.

Here is what you are doing: you are comparing the limit as $x\to a$ of two functions: one is $g(x)=\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$, the other one is $f'\circ\xi$.

Your theorem
 successfully concluded the true fact that these two functions have the same limit and that $\lim_{x\to a} f'(\xi(x))$ exists. But: *can* you conclude that $\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)$ exists? The answer is no. When dealing with $f'\circ\xi$, you are calculating the limit of $f'$  only along the points which can be written as $\xi(y)$ for some $y$, but you are completely oblivious of the points that are *not* in that form. As far as you know, there could be an interval $I=(a,b)$ such that $\xi(I)$ does not contain a sequence $a_n\to a$. The corresponding sequence $f'(a_n)$ might (and sometimes will) not converge, or converge to a limit $L'\ne\lim_{x\to a^+} f'(\xi(x))$.